# 'vars' key appearing in associative array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Apologies if this has been asked but I wasn't able to find a clear reason for this happening.

In a helper function I have:
`$map = $CI->load->view('site/view_sitemap', $data, FALSE);`
I have an associative array that I am passing to the view. It's contents are indexed correctly prior to calling `load->view` but afterwards I have this:

```
Array
(
    [view] => site/view_sitemap
    [vars] => Array
    (
        [hardware] => Array
    )
    [return] => 
)
```

When what I want is this and this is what it is prior to the call:

```
Array
(
    [hardware] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

Was hoping someone could shed light on why this is happening and what I can do to have it appear the same as it does prior to the `load->view` call if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you're saying that `$data` contents are "indexed" correctly, but ... we don't know what you believe is correct. I'm thinking your assumption about that is wrong.

Comment: I'm assuming the second print out is `$data`?  What is the first print out and when is it printed out?  Provide a little more context here.  It looks like Codeigniter  is just preparing the data for the view.

Comment: The first printout is `$data` in my CI helper, the second printout is `$data` in the view. Alright I just realized that I need to call the `$hardware` array in the view instead of $data - I feel silly. However the name of the array is dynamic and will change frequently so that presents a problem in calling it in a single view when I won't know what it's name will be.